# How many $3$-digit numbers are there whose sum of digit is $10$?

Tags: combinatorics

**QUESTION :**

> How many three digits number are there whose sum of digit is $10$?

I did it by looking all the numbers from $100$ to $999$.

Is there any other approach?

Comment: Try [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  Note:  you have to take care to handle the first digit correctly (since, presumably, it has to be $>0$ while the other two digits do not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the number be $\overline{a b c}$ which satisfies $a+b+c=10$.

**Solution 1**

We solve the equation for non-negative integers $a,b,c$ first, and the amount of possible solutions is :
$$\dbinom{10+2}{2}=66$$

But note that $a \ne 0$, so we must subtract those solutions whose $a=0$.

$$66-\dbinom{10+1}{1}=55$$

But we also have to subtract those solutions whose $a=10$.

$$55-1=54$$

which is the answer.

**Solution 2**

If $a=1$, then $(b,c)=(0,9),(1,8),(2,7),...,(9,0)$.

If $a=2$, then $(b,c)=(0,8)\sim(8,0)$.

.
.
.

If $a=9$, then $(b,c)=(0,1),(1,0)$.

So the answer is $10+9+8+7+...+3+2=54$

Comment: You haven’t learnt combination yet?

Comment: Elementary Combinatorics?

Comment: Something like that.

Comment: @Mayank $\displaystyle \binom{12}{2}$ simply means $12C2=\frac{12!}{2!10!}$, I hope you understand this....?

Comment: @Mayank If not, I added solution 2, which is much easier to comprehend.

Comment: You can imagine there are 12 empty spots, and you have to choose two of them to place the two “+” symbol, and place the ten “1” in other spots. Each way of placing is a solution for $ a+b+c=10$, where $a,b,c$ are non-negative integers.

Comment: You have ten “1” and two “+”, so you need 12 spots.

Comment: The sum of $a,b,c$ is 10.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You need to find the number of solutions of $$a+b+c=10$$ subject to the constraints $1 \leq a \leq 9$, $0 \leq b \leq 9$, $0 \leq c \leq 9$.

Comment: Is it necessary to write every number in LaTeX?

Comment: It does make the numbers look good. Doesn't it?

Comment: Can you recommend a book,blog, website or YouTube video for understanding constraints? I am still in grade 10 so I don't know much about constraints.

Comment: No, here you need to read the stars and bars method, which @lulu has suggested in comments.